# How to upload a folder to github repo using the CURL

Tags: git, curl, github, bitbucket, github-api

I'm able to upload a file to git repo using CURL but how to upload a directory?.

Using the CURL and git-API I'm able to upload file to repository.

Comment: git only tracks files.  If those files are in a directory it goes along for the ride.  It will not track an empty directory.

Comment: I'm trying to upload a folder which have many files.

Comment: While I'm uploading a file to repo it's only showing the file under src in remote repo, but the folder top of that is not getting pushed there.